# When should I really call the Reload method of the Properties.Settings.Default

Tags: c#, winforms

When should I really call the `Reload` method of the Properties.Settings.Default? Every time when I want to access properties from the persistent storage? Is it really necessary?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase.reload%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for `ApplicationSettingsBase.Reload` states:

> Refreshes the application settings property values from persistent storage.

So yes, you should call it whenever you want to access properties *from the persistent storage*.  What you *didn't* ask was:

> Do I need to load settings from persistent storage every time I want the value?

The answer to that is *no*.  The value will be cached in the application settings object, so you do not need to reload if you just want the cached value.

Answer (score 1):

The real answer for me is *I can't think of a reason to call it at all*. I'll tell you why:

There are two types of settings. User settings and application settings. The user settings are changed on a per-user basis and most probably through a UI that belongs to your application itself. If you change the settings within your application, it already *knows* they have been changed - reload unnecessary.

The application settings should not change after the application has been installed. How should they? Only admins have access to the program files folders at all.

Applications that run outside user space (services) have no GUI and there's no good reason to use user settings for services. Normally you'll change the config file and then restart the service.

The settings are loaded once when the application is started. Should you re-read them every time before you access a setting? No - for the reasons I gave above.

Comment: "If you change the settings within your application"... sometimes your settings will change from outside your application. Ex: modifying the config file for a service while the service is running, for example via a separate GUI application.

Comment: @JensEhrich Which in most cases does not work, at least not if the service is installed in C:\Program Files [(x86)], because a GUI application (unless run by the Admin) is not allowed to change that file anyway.

Comment: I think you need to call Reload when two instances of an application are running and both are saving changes to the settings.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of when to use Reload() method:

I have built an editor for those property settings. It is a propertygrid control with a few buttons on a dialog form.

When the user clicks to invoke that editor then key/values from Properties.Settings.Default are shown in the propertygrid.

Now, users can change many properties but if they decide NOT to save those changes, settings have to be reloaded because they are now invalid!

And that is when I use:

```
((ApplicationSettingsBase)propertyGrid.SelectedObject).Reload();
```